# Zero measurability of the set of roots of a collection of polynomials

Tags: measure-theory, polynomials

Let $f_i :[0,1]^d \to \mathbb R$ for $i=0,1,\dots,n$ be smooth functions. Consider polynomials $$p_a(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n f_i(a) x^i$$ in $\mathbb R[x]$ indexed by $a \in [0,1]^d$.

Let $\text{Zer}(p_a)$ be the set of (real) roots of $p_a$. We know that $|\text{Zer}(p_a)| \le n$ for all $a$. Is the set $$\bigcup_{a \in [0,1]^d} \text{Zer}(p_a)$$ measurable with measure zero?

EDIT: OK... I realized there was a mistake in my statement. (I am going to leave it there because YCor's comments refer to it)  That set is not measure zero in general. My question was in fact the following: Is the set $\{(a,x) :\; p_a(x) = 0\}$ of zero (Lebesgue) measure in $[0,1]^d \times \mathbb R$. I assume this is at least true, when $f_i(a)$ are polynomials.

Comment: It's clearly measurable since it's closed: $\{(a,x):p_a(x)=0\}$ is closed in $[0,1]^d\times\mathbf{R}$ and the projection $[0,1]^d\times\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$ is a proper map hence is a closed map.

Comment: Great! I see... now the hard part. Does it have measure zero?

Comment: There's no hard part. If $f_0(a)=1$ ,$f_1(a)=a_1$, $f_i(a)=0$ for $i\ge 2$, then $p_a(x)=a_1x-1$ so the union of zeros is equal to $[1,+\infty[$.

Comment: Oh.... good, thanks. I completely missed this. But let us say $f_i$ are themselves polynomials and d > 1. Wouldn't the set $\{(a,x) : p_a(x) = 0\}$ be singular in $[0,1]^d \times \mathbb R$. In your example, the set $\{(a_1,x):\; a_1 x-1 = 0\}$ has zero measure in $\mathbb R^2$, but the projection causes the problem.

Comment: No, in this case ($f_i$ polynomials, no more restriction) the projection is a constructible subset of $\mathbf{R}$, hence a finite boolean combination of intervals. So it's of zero measure only if it's finite.

Comment: @YCor, can you elaborate on that? How do you conclude that the projection is of that form? Would the result change if I have polynomials in two variables $p_a(x,y)$?

Comment: OK, I guess the number of variables doesn't solve anything.

Comment: @YCor, one last comment: In your example isn't the set of zero $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: For semialgebraic sets, see https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/michel.coste/polyens/RASroot.pdf

Comment: @YCor, thanks for the nice reference. (I realized that my question, after correction, reduces to what I always assumed to be true: the zero set of a nontrivial system of polynomial equations has zero measure. )

Comment: What if all $f_i$ are identically $0$?

Comment: @passerby51 Did you ever find an answer for the edited question (that the zero set of a nontrivial system of polynomial equations has measure zero)? I realize that this question is not new, but I'm looking for this very answer right now...